# Desktop Python App with Online Storage

Tags: python, ssl, rethinkdb

I am looking for a 'sanity check' before I start working on this, as I'm new to writing server-side code. I want to stick to Python if possible, since that's what I'm used to!

I have written a desktop app (wxPython) that allows offsite employees to record their working times, the results of which they currently email to the company. I want to be able to have them save data directly to an 'online' location, from which the company can get summary data.

From what I have read (mostly here on StackOverflow) leads me to think I should do the following:

1. Run a database on the server with local access only (I'm favouring RethinkDB...)
2. Write a Python server app that can access the database but only exposes the functionality needed per user. Probably with different ports for users, payroll, and admin (me). Secure the sockets with TLS.
3. Add code to the desktop app to access the server.

Is this a good approach, or am I reinventing wheels and should learn to use Django or some other web framework?

Comment: There's no reason not to do both. You can create a web application with a RESTful API that you access from your existing desktop application.

Comment: Ah, thank you. This is the kind of advice I need :-)
It looks like web.py is a good way to go for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paulo Almeida suggested in the comments making a REST application you interface with your wxPython application is probably the way to go. For this django may be a solution but it is probably an overkill microframework such as [web.py](http://webpy.org/), [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)  or [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/) is enough and more easier to grasp

Comment: As a supplementary question: Is there anything to stop me using ports 80 and 443 for communication between the desktop app and the web server? The app is intended to run without admin privilege (from a USB stick) so should use ports that are likely to be open in the firewall.

Comment: if you are running unix there is few things to do to run an app in ports 80 and 443. But it is well supported by server like apache or nginx which likely use to run your app in production.